# Iterate through a multilevel yaml map using a jinja2 template

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2

Currently I'm trying to access YAML keys that lie in different map "levels" by looping through all keys. Looping through the first two "levels" works but not deeper than that. The code still runs. It just doesn't enter the next loop.

I've tried different variants of for loops:

yaml:

```
---
root:
- key1: bla
  key2: bla
  sub:
    key3: bla
    key4: bla
    map: {key5: bla, key6: bla, key7: bla} 
    sub:
    - key8
.
.
.
```

jinja2 template:

```
{% for l0 in root %}
test0
  {% for l1 in l0.sub %}
  test1
    {% for l2 in l1.sub %}
    test2
      {% for l3 in l2.sub %}
      test3
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for any help I can get!

Comment: I don't believe the sample data and code you're presented here actually demonstrate the problem you've described. Please update your question so that the sample data, when used with the included template, will reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`root` contains a sequence. So your outermost loop iterates over the items of the sequence in `root`, that's fine.

The second loop queries the value of `sub` from the current item. `sub` contains not a sequence, but a mapping. A mapping is loaded into a Python dict object. In Python a `for` loop over a dict object iterates over the keys. Thefore, `l1` will contain the following string values during the iterations:

```
"key3"
"key4"
"map"
"sub"
```

Since these are all strings, `l1.sub` is nonexistent and therefore, the third loop is never executed.

Now, to fix this, you need to think about what the data means. It's strange that the nested `sub` at line 9 does contain a sequence again while the initial `sub` at line 5 does not. Perhaps your problem is in the data and the outer `sub` actually should contain a sequence?

Executing your template on the following data will use the inner loops:

```
---
root:
- key1: bla
  key2: bla
  sub:
  - key3: bla  # note the additional `-` here
    key4: bla
    map: {key5: bla, key6: bla, key7: bla} 
    sub:
    - key8
      sub:    # added to reach the innermost loop
      - key9
...
```

If the data is correct, you should instead think about whether you really want to do the `l1` loop or if you want to do this instead:

```
{% for l1 in l0.sub.sub %}
```

This directly descends into the inner `sub` which actually is a sequence.

Comment: Wow thanks! This really helped me to get a better understanding of the YAML Syntax.